# How do I find userip and useragent?

Tags: jsonp

I am new to programming and I am trying to practice using APIs from third party websites to pull data to my own site. I am trying to use the Glassdoor API but I don't know where I find the required values for UserAgent and the UserIP. This is Glassdoor's explanation:

**userip**    The IP address of the end user to whom the API results will be shown.

**useragent**     The User-Agent (browser) of the end user to whom the API results will be shown. Note that you can can obtain this from the "User-Agent" HTTP request header from the end-user.

Note that for now I just want to pull some data onto a test website on my own computer and simply print the JSONP results onto the page. Where do I find these values? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble and think I can answer your question:

1. You can find your user IP address by simply Googling "what is my IP address." Google will give you the correct answer in the results or you can use another site like http://www.whatismyip.com/
2. Your user agent info is basically the info that identifies which browser is being used, what version, and on which operating system. You can also google this and be provided with the string or you can open up your console (right click in the browser window --> inspect elements --> console) and type navigator.userAgent which will give you the info you seek.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your IP address lookup in your code rather than googling it.  For example, in R:

```
Require(RCurl)
Require(rjson)
str_info <- getURL('http://ipinfo.io') 
data <- fromJSON(str_info)  
userip <- paste("userip=",data$ip, sep = "")
```